# How to propagate MotionEvent but still receive all event coming after ACTION_DOWN in Android?

Tags: android, ontouchlistener, motionevent, ontouch, event-propagation

I'm working on an SDK in which I set an `OnTouchListener` to 2 different views from two different classes that each one of them needs to handle the same touch events for its purposes.

Until now I only needed the `ACTION_DOWN` event in one of them so the method was written as follows:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    ABLogger.d("onTouch Walkthrough handler");
    if (event.getAction() != MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        return false;
    }

    return onAction(v, event);
}
```

And it was working well as I was receiving the `ACTION_DOWN` event passing `false` as a return value, and the following events would be propagated to the next view and its listener in line.

Now I need to test in this method that scroll wasn't committed, in order to do that I need to receive here the `ACTION_UP` event as well. But I won't receive it unless I pass `true` in the return of this method. But if I do that the next listener in line does not receive the events anymore.

**The question is:** How can I receive all the events in both listeners, or at least receive the event in one of them and force it to pass the event to the second one as well?